# Google fit API: How to get a map of the route taken during the activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-fit

I'm using Google Fit API to develop a fitness app.

Take a look at this picture of a google fit recorded session on the Google fit app:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2ykP.png)

I would like to know if it's possible to get the map displayed at the top of the screen. In fact, I know how to call the History API to get sessions but I can't figure out how to get the map displaying the route taken during the activity by the user.

I found this possible duplicate topic (unanswered): [Google fit api: get distance/calories/speed when tracking running/biking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923367/google-fit-api-get-distance-calories-speed-when-tracking-running-biking)

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score -1):

With Reference to [Google Developer Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/fitness-apps-on-android-wear.html)

Using the [Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/wear?utm_campaign=wear-fit-615&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog), you can show users their ***route***, ***position***, and ***place markers*** on the map they can tap to see more info you provide. 
All of this functionality is available to you using the same Maps API you’ve already worked with on Android. Check out the [doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/wear?utm_campaign=wear-fit-615&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog),

> [DevByte](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEyvaILFBWk)
>
> [code sample](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/AndroidWearMap)
>
> [blog post](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/05/the-world-on-your-wrist-google-maps-api.html)

to learn more.

Comment: The links you provide concerns Android Wear. It's not what I need.
I already have a map displayed in my app. I know how to use google maps api. What I want is to know how to get the route of an activity session from google fit API.

Comment: same API can be use with app.